# How to get value and data attribute form input using jQuery .map function

Tags: jquery

I have a series of checkbox inputs with the following format.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="xyz" value="124" data-info="some info">
```

I am using jquery to select the inputs that are checked and trying to get the value and data-info using the `.map()` function and use it in an ajax request.  I can get the value like this.

```
checked_options = $(button).parent().find('input:checkbox:checked').map(function () {
      return this.value;
    }).get();
```

But I can't figure out how to get the value and the data-info and return them as an array or object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method like:

```
checked_options = $(button).parent().find('input:checkbox:checked').map(function () {
  return this.value + ',' + $(this).data('info');
}).get();
```

**Edit:**

You can create an array of objects containing value and data-info like

```
checked_options = $(button).parent().find('input:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
  return {
    v: this.value,
    d: $(this).data('info')
  };
}).get();

console.log(checked_options); // Array of objects as result here
```

Comment: ok I was actually able to get the data using `$(this).attr("data-desc")` as well but I was not wanting to return them concatenated, but as an object or array.  Sorry I was not clear. I edited my question.

Comment: I have updated the code. Please check your browser console if the result is in correct format.